# Change snapping boundary

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, snapping

[Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html) it says when using "snap to grid", that it snaps when I am within 2 px of the grid

> When the object’s boundaries come within 2 pixels of a gridline, it snaps to the point.

How can I change that? I want to move objects in smaller steps than that.

Comment: I find its related to your ZOOM level more than the pixel size of your artwork - IE 2 SCREEN pixels - so try the same zoomed right in.

Answer (score 2):

Change the **Snapping Tolerance** in the Preferences.

[image]

But honestly if 2 pixels is too large a distance, you should be zoomed in viewing the pixel grid, because the only smaller increment is 1 pixel which the pixel grid handles.

Comment: I thought this was only for the smart guides. I'll try it out later, thanks.

Comment: This did not help unfortunately. I changed my grid such that I have a gridline every 80 px with 4 subdivisions. That means the smallest boxes are 20x20 px in size. I changed the snapping tolerance to 2 px. However when I e.g. move an anchor it snaps to the grid all the time.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. If you activate "snap to grid" it *always* snaps to the grid!

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked to *uncheck* `View / Snap to Pixel` and `View / Snap to Point`.

[image]

Comment: The OP is asking to decrease the incremental value by which gridline snapping works. Turning pixel snapping and point snapping off and on will not reduce the incremental values.

Comment: Oh hey @Abhimanyu thanks for setting me straight. I concur with your astute evaluation. Also I wish you continued success in your endeavors of down voting new contributors.

Comment: I have not downvoted your answer.

Comment: @Abhimanyu - please accept my apologies. This discussion has reached a level of pettiness that I totally respect... I am going to slam the fridge door over my head now.

Comment: Just relax. Your answer is not an answer. I merely pointed out why. This is not a discussion, I have not downvoted your answer it was -1 when I found it while reviewing first answerers. If you really want to do all this work, I recommend trying to point out how your answer adds value instead of attempting forced sarcasm, which clearly isn't working over nothing.